# Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadToggleSwitch + coded ui test + c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests

I have a **telerik control** (Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadToggleSwitch) which is used to toggle between state 1 and state 2 with "**Click and drag (left or right)**" to make the toggle effect. I want to do a **hand-coded UI test** to select a state and proceed further. I need a class to call that control(i assumed it is **WinClient**).

I need the proper code to perform toggle action. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may handcode your Coded UI Tests but handcoding your UIControls is really troublesome to do as you can never be sure that the Control you added is actually found and everything you did is correct.
A better alternative is to use the UIMap to manually add your controls via the Coded UI Test Builder. It also saves a lot of time. 
When the Coded UI Test Builder is open you can hover with your mouse over a control and type "Control+I" to get info on that specific control. If you now click on the << on the infobox that opens you see your UIMap with the control you did "Control+I" over on the left added. But the control is not added yet permanently. From here you can add it permanently by clicking on the square with the green plus sign.
[Add Button Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GqNd.png)

Alternatively the easy way is to hover over a control and push "Control+Shift+I".

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code

After adding the specific control to the UIMap you may use it by referecing to the UIMap. When coding in the *.cs file of the UIMaps you can reference to it by the "this" statement.

For example:

```
this.UIWindow.UITitleBar.UICloseButton;
```

When you want to use it outside of the files of the UIMap you have to create an object of the class of the UIMap and then can use it like above by repacing "this" with the object reference.

For example:

```
MyUIMapClass uIMapObject = new MyUIMapClass();
uIMapObject.UIWindow.UITitleBar.UICloseButton;
```

If the file you are coding in is not in the same namespace you have to add a using statement for the namespace of the UIMap (the namespace is defined at the begining of each file in the UIMap).

So for your control I think what you need is Mouse.StartDragging() and Mouse.StopDragging().

```
public static void StartDragging(UITestControl control);
public static void StopDragging(UITestControl control, int moveByX, int moveByY);
```

So a dragging towards left would be:

```
Mouse.StartDragging(UIYourControl)
Mouse.StopDragging(UIYourControl, -20, 0);
```

And toward right:

```
Mouse.StartDragging(UIYourControl)
Mouse.StopDragging(UIYourControl, 20, 0);
```

You should test a bit with the amount you need to drag in each direction for it to register as dragging but I think -20 and 20 should be fine.

I hope I helped a bit. :)